# Weibull regression sensitive to scaling of predictors?

Tags: r, regression, data-transformation, survival, weibull-distribution

I'm running a Weibull regression and decided to simulate data to assure myself that the model is able to recover the true parameters.

```
set.seed(123)
X <- cbind(rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1), rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1))
y <- 1 + X %*% c(2,-2) # true regression coefficients: 2, -2
lm(y ~ 1+X) # a linear model recovers the parameters perfectly (no noise)

library(survival)
t <- rweibull(length(y), shape=1, scale=exp(y)) # scale parameter as a fct of X
survreg(Surv(t, rep(1, length(t))) ~ 1+X, dist='weibull') # ignoring censoring, all events are observed: rep(1, length(t))
```

If you run this code, the recovered estimates are:

```
(Intercept) X1          X2 
1.031724    2.009585   -1.970094
```

If I now rescale the Xs (before creating y):

```
set.seed(123)
X <- cbind(rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1), rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=1))
X <- X / 1000 # rescaling X
y <- 1 + X %*% c(2,-2) # true regression coefficients: 2, -2
lm(y ~ 1+X) # the linear model still recovers the parameters perfectly 

library(survival)
t <- rweibull(length(y), shape=1, scale=exp(y)) # scale parameter as a fct of X
survreg(Surv(t, rep(1, length(t))) ~ 1+X, dist='weibull') # ignoring censoring
```

The new estimates are:

```
(Intercept) X1           X2 
1.042190    14.120545    5.364648
```

How is that possible? It must be an artifact but I don't see how.

Comment: The regression coefficients become much more uncertain and so happen to fall much further away from the true values when you decrease the variances of your covariates.  Your code is also inconsistent in that your first use `T` to store the survival times and then `t` when fitting the model with `survreg`.

Comment: Yes, oh my god, of course, thank you! (The inconsistencies were added when writing the question, sry!)